# Restricting the Lindelöf hypothesis to critical line integer values

Tags: nt.number-theory

Assuming the Lindelöf hypothesis holding along the critical line, it is clear that the following statement ($n$ integers) is true (integers being a subset of the reals):
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+i\,t) = O(t^{\epsilon}) \, \, \,\Longrightarrow \, \, \, \zeta(\frac{1}{2}+i\,n) = O(n^{\epsilon}) $$ 
Let us now suppose that it were possible to prove a "weaker form" of the Lindelöf hypothesis, restricted to integers values along the critical line, the converse statement:
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+i\,n) = O(n^{\epsilon}) \, \, \,\Longrightarrow \, \, \, \zeta(\frac{1}{2}+i\,t) = O(t^{\epsilon}) $$
would it also be true, or rather false? or perhaps, as yet unknown?

In other words, would proving said "weaker form" be sufficient to prove the Lindelöf hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it. The zeta function has lots of zeros on the critical line and, for those zeros of the form $1/2+ i\gamma, \zeta(1/2+i\gamma)=0 = O(|\gamma|^{\epsilon})$, trivially. So, stepping on an infinite sequence is not enough (and we know that there are many more imaginary parts of zeros than integers even without RH). Now, nobody expects the $\gamma$'s to be integers (quite the contrary) but we don't have a proof of that. So my guess is that knowing "Lindelöf" for the integers is not enough.

Comment: Wouldn't this "quite the contrary" follow from a disproof of the natural strengthening of Mertens' conjecture, namely  $ M(x)\ll\sqrt{x} $?

Comment: The Lindelöf hypothesis is equivalent to the weak moment conjecture: $\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^T |\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)|^{2k} \ll_{k,\varepsilon} T^{\varepsilon}$, for each $k = 1,2,\ldots$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. The good thing of this interpretation is that it allows us to fix $k, \varepsilon$ and work asymptotically in $T$. Now you just need an $\ll_{k,\varepsilon} T^{1+\varepsilon}$ bound on the oscillation (total variation) of the integrand on $[0,T]$ to compare it to its Riemann sum over the integer points. The zeros are only $O(T\log{T})$, so my first guess is this ought to be possible.

Comment: On further thought, it seems that proving this bound on the total variation of $\zeta^{2k}(\frac{1}{2} + it)$ on $[0,T]$ would be just as hard as the original problem. So I think I agree with you.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. I thus gather that the general impression is that a definite answer is yet unknown, and that to prove such statement would probably turn out just as difficult as proving the "full" Lindelöf hypothesis itself.

Comment: As to the "we don't expect the Riemann zeta zeros to be integers", also take a look at the paper of Li and Radziwill on the Riemann zeta function along arithmetic progressions on the critical line: https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2684 (Theorem 4).